# Добавочная частица

Tags: частица

Добрый день!

В данном предложении к примеру:

1.**Он сказал то, что все хотели услышать** ... или **Он сказал, что все хотели**..
2. **Я не понимаю того, что они**..  или **Я не понимаю, что они**...

Когда нужно писать добавочную частицу и местоимение, а когда нет? Очень часто сталкиваюсь с этим.

С большим уважением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Надо различать три вида придаточных:**

1) **местоименно-определительные** с обязательной парой указ. слово ТО — союзное слово ЧТО;

2) **изъяснительные,** союз ЧТО; указательное слово факультативно, зависит от семантики глагола.

3) **изъяснительные**, союзное слово ЧТО, нет указательного слова.

1)  **Местоименно-определительные:** Он сказал **то, что** все хотели услышать. Он говорит **о том, что** уже давно известно. Я не понимаю **того, о чем** они говорят.

2) **Изъяснительные**, союзная связь, факультативное указательное слово: Он сказал, **что** все хотели бы услышать его выступление.  Я понимаю, **что** разговор закончен.

Он говорил **(о том), что** все давно уже знают эту новость.

3) **Изъяснительные**, союзное слово, нет указательного слова.
Я не понимаю, **чтО** они хотят этим сказать. Я не понимаю,  **о чЁм** они говорят.

Comment: Т.е, если мы что-то конкретизируем в предложении, то добавляем указательное слово; если обобщаем - убираем указательное слово.   Правильно?

Comment: Если не вникать в грамматические тонкости, то я бы обобщила тему так: указательное слово нужно тогда, когда предложение без него не читается (Он говорит о том, что уже давно известно).  В других случаях лучше обойтись без указательного слова, потому что  оно или факультативно, или вообще невозможно, как в следующем примере: Я понимаю, что разговор закончен.

Comment: Большое спасибо за дополнение.

Answer (score 0):

*Предостережение.*

На наших глазах родился новоблагословенный подчинительный союз "точто"!

Он сказал точто скоро уезжает.

Мы все видим точто власть о нас заботится.

Я думаю точто мне предстоит еще много работы.

И так далее...
Пока наши ведущие грамматисты и стилисты официально не благословили его употребление, такой "союз" следует считать грубой ошибкой.

Теперь о ваших примерах. У вас не союзы, а союзные слова.

Он сказал [именно] **то**, что все хотели услышать.

Я не понимаю, что они хотят. ["Того" здесь лишнее]

Я не понимаю **того**, что они сделали. [Они что-то там усовершенствовали, а вот **что** именно и каким образом, мне непонятно].

Comment: Желательно сформулировать, в чем разница между: "Я не понимаю, что они сделали (нарисовали)" и ""Я не понимаю того, что они сделали (нарисовали)"

Comment: Да, очень важно.

Answer (score 0):

Постараюсь сформулировать, в чем я вижу разницу между "Я не понимаю, что они..." и "Я не понимаю того, что они..." Первое означает, что я не понимаю, о каком объекте идет речь, второе - не понимаю сути, свойств этого объекта.

Например:

"Я не понимаю, что они говорят". Не понимаю, что именно они говорят. То ли из-за того, что плохо слышно, то ли они говорят на другом языке.

"Я не понимая того, о чем они говорят." Не понимаю смысла сказанного, хотя все слова и предложения понятны. Или суть сказанного мне непонятна, или предмет обсуждения мне непонятен.